# Factorial Function (Decreasing by 2)

Tags: factorial

If the factorial function is n*(n-1)*(n-2)...
Then what would the **function** n*(n-2)*(n-4)... be?

Comment: This is called the double factorial https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial